# how to convert curl --data-binary to python request?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have the curl command:

```
curl 'https://example.com/submit' \
    -H 'Accept: */*' \
    -H 'Referer: http://www.example.com/go/' \
    -H 'Origin: http://www.example.com' \
    -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36' \
    -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0' \
    --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"\r\n\r\Oleg\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="campaignCode"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="validation"\r\n\r\n{"firstName":"required"}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0--\r\n' \
    --compressed
```

with:

```
--data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundary...'
```

but my converted version to python code does not work

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'http://www.example.com/go',
    'Origin': 'http://www.example.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0'
}

data = '$------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"\\r\\n\\r\\Oleg\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="campaignCode"\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="validation"\\r\\n\\r\\n{"firstName":"required"}\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0--\\r\\n'

response = requests.post('https://example.com/submit', headers=headers,
                         data=data)
```

Maybe I'm missing something? how to convert `--data-binary $`?

The curl command returns: `{"success":true,"count":1}`, but pycode returns: `{"success":false,"count":1}`

**Also errors:**

1. Without `$` in `data`string response-`{"success":false,"count":0}`.
2. Using a `bytes` instead of a `str` for `data`.

---

**UPDATES:**

this curl command works with curl 7.58.0 on my linux, but on windows- cmd command returns the same error as in the pycode without `$`

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What happens? And, given that the headers aren't exactly the same, why are they different, and why are you sure that doesn't matter?

Comment: Anyway, if you want to specify the exact binary bytes, you can use a `bytes` instead of a `str` for `data`, which seems to be what you're asking for. But, given that your string is pure ASCII, I can't imagine that it would make a difference.

Comment: @abarnert I corrected headers.
when i'm using the curl command server returns {"success":true}, but if pycode {"success":false}
yes, `bytes` instead of `str` dont resolve my problem.

Comment: Why are you including the `$` in your `requests` data (not sure why you need it in your `cURL` call either, given that it's not expanding into anything)?

Comment: @zwer bcse https://curl.trillworks.com/ converted with `$`, anyway this fix cant help me

Answer (score 0):

The payload of a captured packet of your "curl" version :

```
MIME Multipart Media Encapsulation, Type: multipart/form-data, Boundary: "----WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0"
    [Type: multipart/form-data]
    First boundary: ------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part: 
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"\r\n
        Data (6 bytes)
            Data: 0d5c4f6c6567
            [Length: 6]
    Boundary: \r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part: 
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="campaignCode"\r\n\r\n
    Boundary: \r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part: 
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="validation"\r\n\r\n
        Data (24 bytes)
            Data: 7b2266697273744e616d65223a227265717569726564227d
            [Length: 24]
    Last boundary: \r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0--\r\n
```

The payload of a captured packet of your "python" version :

```
MIME Multipart Media Encapsulation, Type: multipart/form-data, Boundary: "----WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0"
    [Type: multipart/form-data]
    Preamble: 242d2d2d2d2d2d5765624b6974466f726d426f756e646172...
    First boundary: ------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part: 
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="campaignCode"\r\n\r\n
    Boundary: \r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part: 
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="validation"\r\n\r\n
        Data (24 bytes)
            Data: 7b2266697273744e616d65223a227265717569726564227d
            [Length: 24]
    Last boundary: \r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0--\r\n
```

The first entry seem to be not recognized normaly.

You should remove `"$"` from head of variable `data` in python code.

```
data = '------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"\\r\\n\\r\\Oleg\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="campaignCode"\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="validation"\\r\\n\\r\\n{"firstName":"required"}\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0--\\r\\n'
```

---

Then, the payload of a captured packet of your **new** "python" version:

```
MIME Multipart Media Encapsulation, Type: multipart/form-data, Boundary: "----WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0"
    [Type: multipart/form-data]
    First boundary: ------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part: 
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"\r\n
        Data (6 bytes)
            Data: 0d5c4f6c6567
            [Length: 6]
    Boundary: \r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part: 
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="campaignCode"\r\n\r\n
    Boundary: \r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part: 
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="validation"\r\n\r\n
        Data (24 bytes)
            Data: 7b2266697273744e616d65223a227265717569726564227d
            [Length: 24]
    Last boundary: \r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0--\r\n
```

This is same with "curl" version.

Comment: thanks for the answer! 
I tried this combination- the server returns {"success":false,"count":0} , not {"success":true,"count":1} .

Comment: this curl command works with curl 7.58.0 on my linux machine, but on windows- cmd command(copied form my browser) returns the same error as in the pycode. hmm

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your two commands aren't sending the same data.

Assuming you're running this in bash or a similar shell, `$'-----blahblah…'` doesn't mean the string `'$-----blahblah…'`, it means the contents of the environment variable `'-----blahblah…'` if there is one, or the string `'-----blahblah…'` if there isn't. Since there almost certainly is no variable with that name, you just get the string—without the leading `$`.

But in Python, you're including the `$` as part of the data. This means you've got an extra entry, the `$`, before the first multipart boundary.

To fix that, just don't do that. Instead of this:

```
data = '$------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"\\r\\n\\r\\Oleg\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="campaignCode"\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="validation"\\r\\n\\r\\n{"firstName":"required"}\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0--\\r\\n'
```

… do this:

```
data = '------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"\\r\\n\\r\\Oleg\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="campaignCode"\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="validation"\\r\\n\\r\\n{"firstName":"required"}\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundaryFkQeCsmEXjVI5SJ0--\\r\\n'
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but this fix also returns False and count 0 instaed of 1. {"success":false,"count":0}

Comment: i think the server means string-counts